# R results two different values of Cronbach Alpha

Tags: r, cronbachs-alpha

I'm a programmer and I needed to do a Cronbach's alpha method to compute statistics. I tried to write a code but I got two values of alpha:

```
library(psych)
MyData <- read.csv(file="C://path//data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
alpha(MyData)
```

The result was

```
  raw_alpha std.alpha G6(smc) average_r S/N   ase mean   sd
      0.47      0.96       1      0.36  24 0.044  3.6 0.68

 lower alpha upper     95% confidence boundaries
0.39 0.47 0.56
```

Am I doing the analysis correctly, as I have been told by an expert that the alpha should be $>0.8$ in this analysis and data rather than $0.47$, or is the value $0.96$ the correct alpha value?

Comment: Why would you believe that it must be greater than 0.8?  Apparently for this data the point estimate is 0.47 and the 95% upper confidence bound is only 0.56.  Isn't std.alpha a standard deviation rather than an estimate?

Answer (score 1):

Five years later and you are probably no longer looking for the answer. Others who are directed to this post, like I was, may be interested in knowing, however.

From the documentation of `alpha` in the [psych package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.2.3/topics/alpha), we see that `raw_alpha` is based on covariance and `std.alpha` is a standardised version based on correlation instead. The formula for Cronbach's alpha, as given in Field (2018), is
$$
\alpha = \frac{(N^2 \overline{cov})}{\sum{} s^2_{item} + \sum{cov_{item}}}
$$
which indicates that Cronbach's alpha is calculated based on the covariances and not on correlations.

Unless you know for sure that you are looking for the standardised version of alpha, I believe you want to use `raw_alpha`.

### References

Field, A. (2018). *Discovering statistics using IBM SPSSS Statistics* (5. Ed.). Sage Publications.